# How to run VB script on all files in a directory?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I would like to run a Visual Basic script called "cscript" on all the files in a directory, rather than a single file at a time. Is this possible?

The manual, one-at-a-time command is:

```
cscript "C:\Program Files\Jampal\ptts.vbs" -w sample.wav < sample.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to run all VBScripts in the directory, or do you want to run a particular VBScript on all files in that directory?

Comment: I would like to run a particular VBScript (cscript) on all the .txt files in that directory. As of now, the script requires the original, existing file name (ie sample.txt) as well as the output's  name to-be (sample.wav). As far as the language goes, I do not have a preference.

Comment: there is a command called For-Files syntax= forfiles [/p <Path>] [/m <SearchMask>] [/s] [/c "<Command>"] [/d [{+|-}][{<Date>|<Days>}]] this works for windows 7 and up from what I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple one liner from the command line without any need for a batch script.

I can't tell if your VB script creates the .wav file or if it uses the file.

If your script creates the .wav file, then:

```
for %F in (*.txt) do cscript "C:\Program Files\Jampal\ptts.vbs" -w "%~dpnF.wav" <"%F"
```

If your script needs both the .txt and .wav file, then you should verify both exist before attempting to process:

```
for %F in (*.txt) do if exist "%~dpnF.wav" cscript "C:\Program Files\Jampal\ptts.vbs" -w "%~dpnF.wav" <"%F"
```